# How to copy all files from a directory and all its nested subdirectories in npm?

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules

I want to copy all files (unknown what their names are before hand) in npm, from a structure similar to this:

```
maindir
 -> subdir1
   -> subSubdir1
     -> filea.js
   -> file.js
 -> subdir2
   -> fileb.js
 -> filec.js
```

I want them to be "flattened" (no subdirectories) in the out directory. And I only want "*.js" files.

I tried (package.json script):

```
#None of these options works
"copy-files": "copyfiles -f maindir/**/** out"
"copy-files": "copyfiles -f maindir/**/*.js out"
```

What would the matching expression be?

Comment: What guarantee is there that conflicting file names won't exist? By putting them all on the same level, you create duplicate file paths, which is not possible on traditional filesystems. You may be opening your system up to errors or even denial of service attacks if those names are user generated.

Answer (score 3):

This will work to copy files from nested Directories

```
"copyfiles -u 1 \"./src/**/*.html\" \"dist\""
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ncp](https://npmjs.org/package/ncp) module, You can find all of the usage types in given link

```
Usage is simple: ncp [source] [dest] [--limit=concurrency limit] [--filter=filter] --stopOnErr
```

Or you can use [fs-extra](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fs-extra)

Comment: I can't seem to get it to work. I tried this: `ncp maindir out --filter='[a-zA-Z\\-_]+\\.js`. And without the filter, it also doesn't do what I want which is to flatten out the structure.

Comment: try second module fs-extra like this -> fse.copy(inDir, outDir, /.*(.js)$/, (err) => { })

Comment: Is there a way to use fs-extra form command line? As an npm script?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that NCP is supported anymore and you can do this with copyfiles by doing

```
copyfiles soruceDir destinationDir
```

but I would suggest you try the following command line options which will help identify whats going wrong with your copy:

```
copyfiles -VEau soruceDir/** destinationDir
```